# show dialog when long pressed and pop it when finger up

Tags: flutter, dialog, gesturedetector

I want to show a dialog when user long pressed on an item and pop it when finger up but it can't detect tap up.

I put dialog on another GestureDetector and use onTapUp property of it to pop dialog.

```
GestureDetector(
 child: studentIcon(index, context),
 onLongPress: () {
   showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (context) {
         return GestureDetector(
           onTapUp: (detail) {
             Navigator.pop(context);
           },
           child: DialogDetail(
             index: index,
           ),
         );
       });
 },
```

I expect to pop dialog after finger up after long pressed.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it because `AlertDialog` or other `Dialog` does not share a context with the location that `showDialog()` is originally called from. So, they are 2 different contexts.

Comment: Have you work out how to do this

Comment: So you want to show dialog when user will hold a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as there is an `context` problem in `GestureDetector`.
Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480827/flutter-implementing-a-peek-pop-effect/51484951#51484951) answer to implement this thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only maybe not with showDialog method. [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707161)  for a similar question.
You could use an overlay like so:

```
class OverlyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlyDialog({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverlyDialog> createState() => _OverlyDialogState();
}

class _OverlyDialogState extends State<OverlyDialog> {

  OverlayEntry? myOverlayEntry;

  OverlayEntry _buildOverlayDialog() => OverlayEntry(builder: (context) => Dialog(
    child: Text('my overlay dialog'),
  ));


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        OverlayEntry overlayEntry = _buildOverlayDialog();
        Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
        myOverlayEntry = overlayEntry;
      },
      onLongPressEnd: (_) {
        myOverlayEntry?.remove();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make method to open dialog . i provide alert dialog code..

```
 void _showText(BuildContext context) {
   showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Text(
            "User name :${nameEditText.text} \nPassword : ${passwordEditText.text}"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: new Text("OK"))
        ],
      );
    });
   }
   }
```

after that called on button click..

```
     child: RaisedButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            onPressed: () {
             _showText(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              "Submit",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

Comment: The question is to pop the dialog when finger leaves the screen. Using a button to do the action is not what is asking for.